# Excess noise along with Signal in three channels in Amplifier Circuit

Tags: amplifier

I have an Professional AV Received with having 7 channels amplifier. The Power Amplifier is UCD400 and with the input of two stage Buffer amplifier (Op-Amp N5532). All of sudden Three of my Channel provides noise along with signal. I could able to listen the noise without signal also. I have done the trouble shooting and identified that the noise is feeded to amplifier from Pre amp stage. I have checked all the ground path and found okay. The problem is like DC signal mixed up with AC signal. Required any experts help to fix the solution.
[image]

Comment: A DC signal would not make noise unless there is noise on the DC.

Comment: What does it sound like? Most likely supply ripple from some leaky e-cap

Comment: first of all thanks for your response. Its like ground path open and mixing up noise. The noise even heard without the signal applied (Keeping the input terminal open). DC Supply is given to all the Seven Amp modules, But problem is faced only with three modules. If ripples in supply , the noise should be observed in all the channels. Please correct me if I am worng.

Comment: If the wiring is common yes. What does it sound like? You never described the sound